# App to toggle 2G and 3G

Tags: iphone

I just purchased iPhone 5s and as a surprise I see no 2G/3G toggle switch. Am from India and I stay in a place where I have poor 3G connectivity. D we have any app in the App Store that can facilitate this option?

Answer (score 1):

Nope and I quite sure that something like this cannot be changed by an app, even if there was a toggle in the Settings.

Maybe there are solution provided the iPhone is jailbroken.

---

For the record, let me mention that the existence of such a toggle seems to depend on the carrier one use.

Reason for saying that is because I used to have the 3G toggle, but it disappeared after I applied a "[carrier update](http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht1937)" that showed up. Maybe in order to have the 4G toggle appearing? I don't know.

To avoid confusion, carrier updates have nothing to do with iOS updates

Comment: According to one of my carrier's engineers, to whom I spoke recently about this exact issue , the 5s can't do that, only the 5 & lower. My partner & I have the same plan & provider, the only difference is our hardware.

Comment: You mean can't have the 3G toggle back? Yes that is probably true. However, in the iPhone 6 I initially had the 3G toggle and it disappeared after a Carrier Update

Comment: I admit that makes your theory sound extremely plausible, but I'm not sure how my own/partner's setup is explained, other than the obvious, that our provider has us on different profiles because of the hardware. Mine can do true 4G, my partner's only LTE, which doesn't work on the UK system.

Comment: I think that yes it probably does depend on the hardware.  But seems like a bad decision from the providers (unless the iPhone limit them to have only 1 such toggle). Another funny fact is that my provider does not even have 4g support yet, but I still got the toggle(!)